# Can you unpin an Adobe Edge Animate .OAM file in scroll effects once animation is complete?

Tags: jquery, animation, adobe, adobe-edge, muse

In Adobe Muse, I've started playing with scroll effects along with Adobe Edge Animation OAM files. I can get it to animate whilst scrolling easily enough, but I am wanting the animation to stop playing and unpin on the page, so it will continue to scroll through the page as per usual.

The idea is so that I can add multiple animations on one page that you scroll through, finish, then scroll down to next animation.

Can you do this in Adobe Muse? Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easy way to scroll through HMTL5 animation with jQuery?

I am wanting to make a way to make a page like this - https://vimeo.com/cameo

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, and contacting Adobe help, it's been confirmed that this can't be done in Adobe Muse ("once it is pinned, you can't unpin it"). Looks like I was after an easy way to code complex animations..

The solution is to do it manually. Waypoints / Jquery.

A helpful link is `https://elikirk.com/canvas-based-scroll-controlled-backgroud-video-use-parallax-style-web-design/` which i believe is in the right direction. If i ever end up coding it, I will let you know.